# Creating clusters based on attribute and proximity

Tags: qgis, clustering, spatial-cluster

In my map as you see below, I have my population by district.

I want to create 50 clusters with **similiar** sums of the population and by proximity. How I can achieve this?

For each cluster, I want the districts are next to each other (As you can see in yellow in the picture).

[image: Example]

Comment: Have you taken a look at the various tool which pop up when you enter `cluster` in the search window of the tool box?

Comment: yes, it seems they all used clustering with values but without considering the spatial proximity... Like this one : http://www.ekazakov.info/projects/abc_tutorial.html

Comment: DBSCAN definitely uses proximity.

Comment: Yes, but will now not considerate the population factor. SO DBSCAN will only clusters in 50 base on distance...

Comment: @SimonGIS were you able to solve your problem ? Would you mind sharing how ?

Answer (score 1):

Not a full-fledged answer, but:

1. Build an adjacency matrix of your polygons, to know which is adjacent to which. This may be done either through the R provide scripts, or Python, as far as I know there is no current implementation built in QGIS;
2. Search via breadth-first search for the neighbours, and keep on checking whether you got to the population required.

You will need tweaks - you do not say if the population is given by a constant, or determined as a fraction of the overall population.